# How to implement multiple catches with error provider if textbox is empty

Tags: vb.net

I have a program that writes txtboxes to a .txt file, I don't want to be able to "Generate Log Book Entry" until all text boxes are filled in and all check boxes are checked. I have the error provider to pop up correctly, but I need it implemented in the code so that it works the same way as the check boxes (All checkboxes must be checked before you're able to generate log book entry).

```
     'Aircraft make/model textbox cannot be blank
        If Me.TextBox4.Text = "" Then
                ErrorProvider1.SetError(TextBox4, "Cannot be blank")
            Else
                Me.ErrorProvider1.SetError(Me.TextBox4, "")

            End If

            'N-number textbox cannot be blank
            If Me.TextBox3.Text = "" Then
                ErrorProvider1.SetError(TextBox3, "Cannot be blank")
            Else
                Me.ErrorProvider1.SetError(Me.TextBox3, "")
            End If

        'If all checkboxes are checked then no error is shown; if a single checkbox is not check, errorprovider shown 
        If CheckBox1.Checked And CheckBox2.Checked And CheckBox3.Checked And CheckBox4.Checked And CheckBox5.Checked And CheckBox6.Checked And CheckBox7.Checked Then
            ErrorProvider1.SetError(Button2, "")

            Dim FILE_NAME As String = "C:\Users\Blake\Documents\test2.txt" 'Sends information to test2.txt 
            If System.IO.File.Exists(FILE_NAME) = True Then
                Dim objWriter As New System.IO.StreamWriter(FILE_NAME)
                objWriter.Write("Aircraft Make & Model: " & TextBox4.Text & ", N-number: " & TextBox3.Text)
                objWriter.Write(" 
Gascolator Removed & Inspected in accordance with FAA approved maintenance manual")
                objWriter.Write("

Signature _____________________________")
                objWriter.Write(" " & DateTime.Now) 'Displays current date and time
                objWriter.Close()
                MsgBox("Text Written To File")
            Else
                MsgBox("File Does Not Exist")
            End If
        Else ErrorProvider1.SetError(Button2, "All boxes must be checked")
        End If
```

I have tried moving

```
                Me.ErrorProvider1.SetError(Me.TextBox4, "")
            End If
```

but it doesn't allow more than one "If" statement in that section of code.enter image description here

[Doesn't allow text to be written to file bc/ txtboxes are not checked](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ish0o.png)

[Blank boxes able to write in .txt file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oLEbX.png)

[Entered info with .txtfile](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P2YrR.png)

Comment: There's a proper way to go about validation. You should look into the `Validating` and `Validated` events of the controls and also the `ValidateChildren` method of the form. Set error messages in `Validating` event handlers, clear error messages in `Validated` events handlers and call `ValidateChildren` before using the data and don't use it if it returns `False`.

Comment: By the way, give your controls meaningful names.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try restructuring your code like this

```
If Me.TextBox4.Text = "" Then
    ErrorProvider1.SetError(TextBox4, "Cannot be blank")
Else
      Me.ErrorProvider1.SetError(Me.TextBox4, "")
End If
If Me.TextBox3.Text = "" Then
     ErrorProvider1.SetError(TextBox3, "Cannot be blank")
Else
    Me.ErrorProvider1.SetError(Me.TextBox3, "")
    'Add this line here
    validateCheckBoxes()
End If

Sub validateCheckBoxes()
    'Move this part here
    If CheckBox1.Checked And CheckBox2.Checked And CheckBox3.Checked And CheckBox4.Checked And CheckBox5.Checked And CheckBox6.Checked And CheckBox7.Checked Then
        ErrorProvider1.SetError(Button2, "")

        Dim FILE_NAME As String = "C:\Users\Blake\Documents\test2.txt" 'Sends information to test2.txt 
        If System.IO.File.Exists(FILE_NAME) = True Then
            Dim objWriter As New System.IO.StreamWriter(FILE_NAME)
            objWriter.Write("Aircraft Make & Model: " & TextBox4.Text & ", N-number: " & TextBox3.Text)
            objWriter.Write("Gascolator Removed & Inspected in accordance with FAA approved maintenance manual")
            objWriter.Write("Signature _____________________________")
            objWriter.Write(" " & DateTime.Now)
            'Displays current date and time
            objWriter.Close()
            MsgBox("Text Written To File")
        Else
            MsgBox("File Does Not Exist")
        End If
    Else 
        ErrorProvider1.SetError(Button2, "All boxes must be checked")
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for all the help preciousbetine, I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

While the way you did this will eventually work, I would suggest another approach.

There is like a bazillion ways to do this. I would simply disable the "Generate Log" button until the user has checked and filled everything. This would prevent most problems you mentioned, but you wouldn't have the nice error messages I read through your code, so if they are important you won't be able to work this way.

Here's a code snippet that would do just what I just spoke about:

```
'Check if the user is checking boxes
Private Sub Checkboxes_CheckedChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles CheckBox1.CheckedChanged, CheckBox2.CheckedChanged, CheckBox3.CheckedChanged, CheckBox4.CheckedChanged, CheckBox5.CheckedChanged, CheckBox6.CheckedChanged, CheckBox7.CheckedChanged
    UpdateGenerateLogButtonEnabled()
End Sub

'Check if the user is writing text
Private Sub TextBoxes_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles TextBox1.TextChanged, TextBox2.TextChanged
    UpdateGenerateLogButtonEnabled()
End Sub

'Manage the GenerateLog button Enabled state
Private Sub UpdateGenerateLogButtonEnabled()
    GenerateLogBookButton.Enabled = CheckBox1.Checked AndAlso CheckBox2.Checked AndAlso CheckBox3.Checked AndAlso CheckBox4.Checked AndAlso CheckBox5.Checked AndAlso CheckBox6.Checked AndAlso CheckBox7.Checked AndAlso Not TextBox1.Text = "" AndAlso Not TextBox2.Text = ""
End Sub
```

As I stated, there are many, many ways to validate this kind of code. If you need your error messages, you'll want a different one. Either way, have fun!